# CSS Animation/ Moving an image up the screen with @KEYFRAMES

Tags: css, animation

Hi I am trying to move a image up the screen using CSS. Currently when I run it just appears at the top of the page. Here is the code I am trying. I am trying to run this in chrome.

```
<head>

<style>
#float{
width: 200px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
animation: floatBubble 2s inifnate;
animation-directon: normal;
}


@keyframes floatBubble{
 0% {
        top:0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

   }


   100% {
      top: 500px;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   }

}
</style>

</head>
<body  style="background-color:#FF9900; color:#CC0033; text-align:center">

<div id="float">
<img src ="bub.png" height="100px" width="100px" alt="bubbles">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: way to spell `infinite` buddy. :P also, u have a vendor prefix on the 0%, and not on the 100%? and im assuming ur saying screw u to the 60% of people that don't use Chrome/Safari by the lack of other vendor prefixes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/WmmNQ/2/)**

```
#float {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s infinite  normal ease-out;
    animation: floatBubble 2s infinite  normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
    0% {
        top:500px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0px;
    }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
    0% {
        top:500px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was trying to do. I REALLY appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out :

CSS:

```
<style>
#float{
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
  }


@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble{
 from{
        top:0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

   }


   to {
      top: 200px;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   }

}
</style>
```

I think this is what you want ;)

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ekives/2/)

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your thorough response!! It is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
animation: floatBubble 2s inifnate;
```

to this

```
animation: floatBubble 25s infinite;
```

also, if you're trying to move it UP the screen, instead of 500px , change to -500px