# Have an image fade in, drop, and bounce once into position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an effect where an image fades in and drops down, bounces once before dropping back into the lowest position.

I have the fade in bit done, but its the drops down bounce once before stopping that I cannot get working.

I found this code: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/wozrjg from this topic: [CSS Animation/ Moving an image up the screen with @KEYFRAMES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797187/css-animation-moving-an-image-up-the-screen-with-keyframes) which works quite well with the fade in, but I am not sure how to make it drop, bounce one, and then settle back into the lowest point again.

This is my current version:
http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/mOrBWd

JS

```
$('#gallery img').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i*200).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Delayed image load in</title>
</head>
<style>
#float{
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s 2;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
  }


@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble{
 from{
        top:0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

   }


   to {
      top: 50px;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   }

}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/loyaltyimages/icon1.png" id="float" alt="" width="125" />
    <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/loyaltyimages/icon2.png" id="float" alt="" width="125" />
    <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/loyaltyimages/icon3.png" id="float" alt="" width="125"/>
    <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/loyaltyimages/icon4.png" alt="" width="125"/>
    <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/loyaltyimages/icon5.png" alt="" width="125"/>
    <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/loyaltyimages/icon6.png" alt="" width="125"/>
    <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/loyaltyimages/icon7.png" alt="" width="125"/>
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have the -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; in the keyframe declaration, it does not belong there, it belongs to the #float selector.

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but does how it currently break the code?

Comment: Probably overkill, but have a look at jquery-ui easing

Comment: Had a look at [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) ?

Comment: @freedomn-m - jquery-easing would probably look great, though I want to keep this as simple as possible. Also Jones Joseph - I actually have not looked at Animate.css and will take a closer look at that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOrqOm)

Basically I just got rid of the alternate thing and wrote the animation in percents. And you also need to set the animation-fill-mode to "forwards" so it stays where the animation ends.

```
#float{
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}


@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble{
  0%{
        top:0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  33% {
      top: 50px;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }

  66% {
        top:0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
   }

  100% {
        top:50px;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!